# How to close connection just after getting Long Polling request? (SignalR)

Tags: asp.net, long-polling, signalr

I hit the following problem. Sometimes the server should make a response just after getting the long polling request like this:

/MvcSignalRTest/signalr/?transport=longPolling&...

So I would like the algorithm to work like this:
1) Server get a long polling request.
2) If there is a data to send to the client, do this, close the connection and make the next long polling request.
3) If there is no data to send to the client right now, keep the connection alive.

How can I do this using SignalR?

I tried to use

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<SignalRConnection>("signalR_route", "signalr/*");
```

but actually the application doesn't handle ClientConnected event. Maybe I do some wrong.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you trying to do? Did you read the docs? https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki